# Partition table data are not restored using pg_restore in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Need Help !!

While i'm going to restore a partition table using :

```
pg_restore -U (username) -d (Database) -p (port_number) -t (partition_table) -f (filename)
```

the result is success but the data in that partition table is not restored, can anyone help me ?

Comment: I guess you have to restore the partitions as well.

Comment: but when i'm restoring full database without mentioning the table, the partition table data is restored.

Comment: Sure. But if you tell it to restore the partitioned table and none of the partitions, then only the partitioned table is restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When -t is specified, pg_restore makes no attempt to dump any other database objects that the selected table(s) might depend upon. Therefore, there is no guarantee that the results of a specific-partitioned table dump can be successfully restored

However you can take dump using

pg_dump --host=hostname --username=user -t "child_table_*"  --data-only --file=dump_out.sql dbname

and then restore it, This is probably a consequence of the design decision to have partitions visible as individual tables on the SQL level.

please refer:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgrestore.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pgdump.html